# How to make HTTPPOST

Tags: android, http-post

[i want to send parameter in body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm0Ax.png)
i want to send parameter in body same pic

this code is error:

```
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String html = null;
        try {
            httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response1.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Status OK
                HttpEntity entity = response1.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content,"UTF-8"));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
```

Stacktrace:

03-06 21:01:10.153 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://161.246.37.11 refused
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.example.tao.navi.HttpConnection.getHttpPostBody(HttpConnection.java:116)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.example.tao.navi.Login.doSomethingElse(Login.java:114)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.example.tao.navi.Login.onClick(Login.java:103)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /161.246.37.11 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
03-06 21:01:10.155 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:   ... 19 more
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:   ... 24 more
03-06 21:01:10.156 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi I/Choreographer: Skipped 820 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-06 21:03:40.035 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://161.246.37.11 refused
03-06 21:03:40.036 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
03-06 21:03:40.036 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-06 21:03:40.036 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-06 21:03:40.036 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-06 21:03:40.036 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.example.tao.navi.HttpConnection.getHttpPostBody(HttpConnection.java:116)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.example.tao.navi.Login.doSomethingElse(Login.java:114)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.example.tao.navi.Login.onClick(Login.java:103)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-06 21:03:40.037 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
03-06 21:03:40.038 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-06 21:03:40.038 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-06 21:03:40.038 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
03-06 21:03:40.038 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
03-06 21:03:40.038 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /161.246.37.11 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-06 21:03:40.040 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
03-06 21:03:40.040 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
03-06 21:03:40.040 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
03-06 21:03:40.040 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
03-06 21:03:40.040 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-06 21:03:40.040 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-06 21:03:40.041 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:   ... 19 more
03-06 21:03:40.041 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-06 21:03:40.041 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-06 21:03:40.042 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
03-06 21:03:40.042 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
03-06 21:03:40.042 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
03-06 21:03:40.042 18727-18727/com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:   ... 24 more

Comment: share your stack trace